Strategy: Have 2 take profits and move stoploss to entry
I'm trying since weeks now, to solve a problem and it seems like I'm not able to do it on my own.
I want a strategy, that contains:

two TakeProfit levels (TP1 - 50% | TP2 - 100%)
one main stoploss, when TP1 is NOT hit
move stoploss to entry, after TP1 WAS hit

What I was able to achieve is, that both TakeProfits are being taken correctly.
Problem still is:

When TP1 was NOT hit, but main StopLoss is hit, it will only StopLoss with 50%
When TP1 was hit, it instantly triggers the StopLoss at entry, which doesn't makes sense to me

In the source code below, I just added for now the strategy for a short, as it will be easy to finalize it for the long position when everything works as expected:
//@version=5
strategy("Long/Short Signal [Strategy]", overlay=true, initial_capital = 100000, max_bars_back = 1000) 

// 257  LETZTE RICHTIGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!
///////////////////////////
// Global Variables
////////////////////////
enableRsiRegular =      true 
rsiColorPos =           color.new(color.lime, 0)
rsiColorNeg =           color.new(color.lime, 0)

enableRsiTrendlines =   true
trendlineRcolor =       color.white
trendlineScolor =       color.white

enableDivergences =     input           (   true,                               "    ◉ ON/OFF - DIV",                  group="Show/Hide", inline="Divergence")
showhidden        =     input           (   true,                               "Show hidden DIVs",                    group="Show/Hide", inline="Divergence")

////////////////////////
// Sources
////////////////////////
sourceCLOSE =   close
sourceOPEN =    open
sourceHLC3 =    hlc3
sourceHIGH =    high
sourceLOW =     low

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                                   //
//                       -------------- RSI --------------                           //
//                                                                                   //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
rsiLengthInput =    input.int       (   14,     "RSI",      1,      group="RSI",        inline="RSILength")

var rsiOutput = 0.0
color rsiColor = na
if enableRsiRegular
    // calculation
    rsiOutput := ta.rsi(sourceCLOSE, rsiLengthInput)
    rsiColor := rsiOutput > 50 ? rsiColorPos : rsiColorNeg

// SCALED
rsi_Y =                      50
rsi_Multiplicator =          3  
rsiOutputScaled =   ((rsiOutput-50)*rsi_Multiplicator)+rsi_Y

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//----------------------------- FINAL OUTPUTS --------------------
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
rsiFinalOutput = rsiOutputScaled

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
//                        ====== DIVERGENCES ======                           //
//                                                                            //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import iBeardy/iBeardyDivergenceLib/22 as divergenceIndicators

var isDivergence = divergenceIndicators.Object.new()
var isRegularBearDiv = false
var isRegularBullDiv = false
var isHiddenBearDiv = false
var isHiddenBullDiv = false

if enableDivergences
    isRegularBearDiv := divergenceIndicators.CheckRegularBearDivergences(isDivergence, "RegularBear", false, "0")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
//                      ====== TRENDLINE RSI ======                           //
//                                                                            //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import HoanGhetti/SimpleTrendlines/3 as tl

g_trendlines    = 'Trendline Settings', g_conditions = 'Conditions',  g_styling = 'Styling', g_timeframe = 'Timeframe'
input_pLen      = input.int             (   3,              'Lookback',               group = "RSI Trendlines", inline="RSI Trendlines",   minval = 1, tooltip = 'How many bars to determine when a swing high/low is detected.')
input_repaint   = input.string          (   'On',           'Repaint',                   group = "RSI Trendlines", inline="RSI Trendlines",   options = ['On', 'Off: Bar Confirmation'], tooltip = 'Bar Confirmation: Generates alerts when candle closes. (1 Candle Later)')
input_rsiDiff   = input.int             (   3,              'RSI Difference',               group = "RSI Trendlines", inline="RSI Trendlines",   tooltip = 'The difference between the current RSI value and the breakout value.\n\nHow much higher in value should the current RSI be compared to the breakout value in order to detect a breakout?')
input_override  = input.bool            (   false,          'Override Text Color',          group = "RSI Trendlines")
input_overCol   = input.color           (   color.white,  '',                             group = "RSI Trendlines")
input_checkDivs = input.bool            (   true,          "With regular DIV check?",  group = "RSI Trendlines")
input_checkHiddenDivs = input.bool      (   false,          "With hidden DIV check?",  group = "RSI Trendlines")

lblText = 'Br'

repaint = switch input_repaint
    'On' => true
    'Off: Bar Confirmation' => false


rsiX = rsiFinalOutput
outputFinal =  rsiX

pl = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(outputFinal, 1, input_pLen))
ph = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(outputFinal, 1, input_pLen))

pivot(float pType) =>
    pivot = pType == pl ? pl : ph
    xAxis = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(pivot), bar_index, 0) - ta.valuewhen(ta.change(pivot), bar_index, 1)
    prevPivot = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(pivot), pivot, 1)
    pivotCond = ta.change(pivot) and (pType == pl ? pivot > prevPivot : pivot < prevPivot)
    pData = tl.new(x_axis = xAxis, offset = input_pLen, strictMode = true, strictType = pType == pl ? 0 : 1)
    pData.drawLine(pivotCond, prevPivot, pivot, outputFinal)
    pData

trendlineRcolor :=  enableRsiTrendlines ? trendlineRcolor : na
trendlineScolor := enableRsiTrendlines ? trendlineScolor : na

strategyDetails(direction, entryPrice, TP1, TP2, SL)=>
    textOutput = "ENTRY: "+str.tostring(entryPrice)   +    "\nTP1: "+str.tostring(TP1)    +   "\nTP2: "+str.tostring(TP2)     +   "\nSL Main: "+str.tostring(SL)   +   "\nSL Moved: "+str.tostring(entryPrice)
    if direction == "short"
        short1 = label.new(bar_index, na, yloc = yloc.abovebar, text = textOutput, color = color.new(color.red, 50) ,size = size.small, textcolor = input_override ? color.new(trendlineScolor, 50) : color.new(trendlineScolor, 50)) 
    if direction == "long"
        long1 = label.new(bar_index, na, yloc=yloc.belowbar, text = textOutput, color = color.new(color.green, 50), size = size.small, textcolor = input_override ? color.new(trendlineScolor, 50) : color.new(trendlineScolor, 50), style=label.style_label_up)

breakout(tl.Trendline this, float pType) =>
    regularBearDivs = isRegularBearDiv[4] or isRegularBearDiv[3] or isRegularBearDiv[2] or isRegularBearDiv[1] or isRegularBearDiv
    
    var bool hasCrossed = false
    if ta.change(this.lines.startline.get_y1())
        hasCrossed := false
    this.drawTrendline(not hasCrossed)
    condType = (pType == pl ? rsiX < this.lines.trendline.get_y2() - input_rsiDiff : rsiX > this.lines.trendline.get_y2() + input_rsiDiff) and not hasCrossed
    condition = repaint ? condType : condType and barstate.isconfirmed

    highest = ta.highest(high, 5)
    lowest = ta.lowest(low, 5)
    float SL = na
    float entryPrice = na
    float TP1 = na
    float TP2 = na

    if condition and pType == pl
        hasCrossed := true
        this.lines.startline.set_xy2(this.lines.trendline.get_x2(), this.lines.trendline.get_y2())
        this.lines.trendline.set_xy2(na, na)
        this.lines.startline.copy()
        
        // --------------------- Calculation for strategy
        // Entry
        entryPrice := close
        // Main Stoploss
        SL := highest
        // Moved Stoploss after TP1 hit
        movedSL = entryPrice
        // Calculation for the target Price
        calc1 = SL - entryPrice
        calc2 = calc1 * 1.5
        calc3 = calc2 / 2
        // TP1
        TP1 := entryPrice - calc3
        // TP2 (not used yet)
        TP2 := entryPrice - calc2
        // Max loss (not used yet)
        maxLoss = 50
        // Calculation for the quantity of the entered trade
        calc4 = SL - entryPrice
        calc5 = 50*1/calc4

        if regularBearDivs
            textOutput = strategyDetails("short", entryPrice, TP1, TP2, SL)  
            strategy.entry("short1", strategy.short, calc4, comment = "SHORT regular")
            strategy.exit("TP1", "short1",  limit=TP1, qty_percent = 50, stop=SL, comment_profit = "TP1 Short", comment_loss = "Stoploss2 Short")
            strategy.exit("TP2", "short1",  limit=TP2, stop=SL,   comment_profit = "TP2 Short", comment_loss = "Stoploss1 Short")


    hasCrossed

method style(tl.Trendline this, color col) =>
    this.lines.startline.set_color(col)
    this.lines.startline.set_width(1)
    this.lines.trendline.set_color(col)
    this.lines.trendline.set_width(1)
    this.lines.trendline.set_style(line.style_solid)

plData = pivot(pl)
phData = pivot(ph)
plData.style(trendlineRcolor)
phData.style(trendlineScolor)
cu = breakout(plData, pl)
co = breakout(phData, ph)

I tried different approaches but they never work as expected. Also looking for solutions online didn't help me solve the problem.
